# How to fetch data from firestore and inside it fetch another data (by reference)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire5

I can't figure out how to fetch data from firestore when i have in data model reference (id) to another object, for example like this

```
City {name:      string;
       countryId: string; //primary key to another object in database
}
Country {
      name: string;
}
```

I m using AngularFire 5.

After i fetch city i want fetch country and i want to asign country.name to city.countryId and i want return joined object city.
I made service for this because i want fetch this data from multiple places in code.

```
@Injectable()
export class CityService implements  OnInit {
  city: City;

  constructor(
    private dataFetch: FireStoreService) { }
  ngOnInit() {}

  getCity(ref: string): City {
    this.dataFetch.getDataDoc(ref).subscribe((_city: City) => {
      this.dataFetch.getDataDoc(_city.countryId)
        .subscribe((country: Country) => {
          _city.countryId = country.name;
          this.city = _city;
        });
    });
    return this.city;
  }
}
```

Ye i know this will not work beacause it is async task, i have read a lot of articles, but i can not still figure out. So I don't know how to fetch some object and then fetch references from this object and return joined object (without references but with proper data). 
This is my city component.

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-detail-city',
      template: `
        <p> detail-city works! </p>
        <p> Name : {{ city.name }} </p>
        <p> Country : {{ city.countryId }} </p>
        <p> ID : {{ city.id }} </p>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./detail-city.component.css']
    })
    export class DetailCityComponent implements OnInit {
      city: City;
      root: string;

      constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private cityService: CityService) {
        this.route.params.subscribe(
          (params: Params) => {
            this.root = params['root']+'/'+params['id'];

            this.city = cityService.getCity(this.root);

          });
      }
      ngOnInit() {}
    }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion in general , for real database you needed to keep data shallow and so you would end up with multiple queries but in Firestore you don't and I have found a little bit of time to redesigning structure of your database can save you many queries. Not sure what's document and what is collection in your data. Perhaps a better indication or an image?

Comment: can you show your `dataFetch: FireStoreService` code

Comment: [countries](https://ibb.co/eGtqg6) [cities](https://ibb.co/irAQER) There are pictures of structure. @TheeBen

Comment: @Hareesh [FireStoreService](https://ibb.co/h3D98m) I just return observable.

Comment: @magino We don't do "SOLVED" here. If you found your own answer, post it below and mark it as accepted or delete the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i manage to solve this problem at the end.
Here is code from servis.

```
 getCity(ref: string): Observable<City> {
    return this.dataFetch.getDocument(ref)
      .switchMap((res: City) => {
        return this.dataFetch.getDocument(res.countryId)
          .map((country: Country) => {
            return new City(
              res.id,
              res.name,
              country.name
            );
          });
      });
  }
```

Then you can subscribe to this observable in your component or use async pipe.
Also, I found usefull [link](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-advanced-usage-angularfire/) where is described how to use reference and geo type in  FireStore.